# mongodb crashed with permission denied error

Tags: mongodb

Our mongodb server was running for the last two months without any error. Suddenly it crashed it below is the log.

```
2017-08-11T13:41:41.320+0100 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (13) [1502455301:320924][1281:0x7f11bce8e700], log-server: /var/lib/mongo/journal: opendir: Permission denied
2017-08-11T13:41:41.320+0100 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (13) [1502455301:320991][1281:0x7f11bce8e700], log-server: dirlist journal prefix WiredTigerPreplog: Permission denied
2017-08-11T13:41:41.321+0100 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (13) [1502455301:321013][1281:0x7f11bce8e700], log-server: log pre-alloc server error: Permission denied
2017-08-11T13:41:41.321+0100 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (13) [1502455301:321021][1281:0x7f11bce8e700], log-server: log server error: Permission denied
2017-08-11T13:41:42.000+0100 I -        [ftdc] Assertion: 13538:couldn't open [/proc/1281/stat] errno:13 Permission denied
2017-08-11T13:41:42.000+0100 W FTDC     [ftdc] Uncaught exception in 'Location13538 couldn't open [/proc/1281/stat] errno:13 Permission denied' in full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem. Shutting down the full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem.
2017-08-11T13:41:50.006+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45196 #205521 (23 connections now open)
2017-08-11T13:41:50.006+0100 I NETWORK  [conn205521] end connection 127.0.0.1:45196 (22 connections now open)
2017-08-11T13:42:36.004+0100 E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (13) [1502455356:4361][1281:0x7f11bb68b700], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: WiredTiger.turtle: fstat: Permission denied
2017-08-11T13:42:36.004+0100 E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (13) [1502455356:4466][1281:0x7f11bb68b700], checkpoint-server: checkpoint server error: Permission denied
2017-08-11T13:42:36.004+0100 E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (-31804) [1502455356:4480][1281:0x7f11bb68b700], checkpoint-server: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2017-08-11T13:42:36.004+0100 I -        [thread2] Fatal Assertion 28558
2017-08-11T13:42:36.004+0100 I -        [thread2] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Could anyone please tell me why it is crashed. We are running mongodb version 3.2.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

Answer (score -1):

> /var/lib/mongo/journal: opendir: Permission denied

The mongos process does not have permission to open its journal files so the process exits with an error.

Comment: hi kailniris, tks for your answer. What should I do to avoid this error in future. note: mongodb is running after just restart. we did not do anything apart from restart

Comment: Are you sure? Was not mongodb updated or any permission group changed or host os updated? Anyway you should use something like this
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb

Comment: In this case,Could you please tell me how come in the middle of the running the file permission got changed. Because it ran for two months without any problem.

Comment: It could be a bug in mongodb itself but I could not found any report like your issue. Check permission change logs. This error happens exclusively when mongodb instance is started without proper permissions. You can submit an issue at jira.mongodb.org.